# Angular 12 - CORS is blocking my request : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, typescript, cors

I'm a web developer student. With my team we're working on an Angular project. We meet an error when we try to call an API : https://pole-emploi.io/data/api/bonne-boite.

Here my config :

- Angular : 12.2.11
- Node : 14.17.6
- Package Manager : npm 8.1.0
- TypeScript : 4.3.5

I've got this error on my console :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://entreprise.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token?realm=%2Fpartenaire' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

With REST CLIENT plugin on VSCode and my request.http file, it works perfectly. The API returns the token, and I use this token to get datas from API. Please, consider I've hidden my client_id, client_secret and scope and replace it by **** here.

Here's request.http :

```
POST https://entreprise.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token?realm=%2Fpartenaire
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=**************
&client_secret=***************
&scope=*******************

###
GET https://api.emploi-store.fr/partenaire/labonneboite/v1/company/?departments=69&rome_codes=M1805
Authorization: Bearer *****************
```

It returns :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-store
Date: Wed, 10 Nov 2021 16:55:07 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: TS0188135e=01b3abf0a2e54b0c97df3456ce071eb19ea227d7e4faa29aad895859b8dc966564047bac9126f72dd30972efee41b2810194364e74; Path=/; Domain=.entreprise.pole-emploi.fr; Secure; HTTPOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close

{
  "access_token": "YhKDCq4VO6R--Zgue4uzFcf08rA",
  "scope": "application_PAR_choptonjob_4e62ba37501087c90968a13a7a1830ffd58dd8d9da9f4d5b94ecb633dd555ebe api_labonneboitev1",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 1499
}
```

When I try to reproduce this request on my service, it fails. Here's my company.service.ts :

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CompanyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }),
  };

  getToken(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      'https://entreprise.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token?realm=%2Fpartenaire',
      'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=*************&client_secret=*************&scope=*************%20api_labonneboitev1',
      this.httpOptions
    );
  }
```

Here's my component :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Card} from '../shared/models/card-result.model';
import {NgbRatingConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {companies} from '../shared/mocks/companies.mock';
import {CompanyService} from '../shared/services/company.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-result-list',
  templateUrl: './result-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./result-list.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbRatingConfig], // add NgbRatingConfig to the component providers
})
export class ResultListComponent {
  // variable which will be used to store the values ​​for each variable of each company in the form of objects in an array
  cards: Card[];
  isShown: boolean;

  constructor(config: NgbRatingConfig, private companyService: CompanyService) {
    this.cards = [];
    // Customize the default max value
    config.max = 5;
    config.readonly = true;
    this.isShown = false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cards = companies;

    this.companyService.getToken().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

This is the errors I've got :
[Network error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFyhk.png)

With my team and my teacher, we've tried a lot of things with no success. Some help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The error kind of explains what needs to happen here, the endpoint `https://entreprise.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token?realm=%2Fpartenaire` needs to return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

If you don't have access to change what `enterprise.pole.emploi.fr` returns (because you don't own this, I'm guessing), you can't fix this.

Browsers will by default block requests that might be unsafe, and it's up to the API owner (`entreprise.pole-emploi.fr` in this case), to create exceptions for that.

Given the request you are trying to do (a `client_credentials` OAuth2 request), this also makes perfect sense to me. Browsers should not know your OAuth2 secrets, you need to make this HTTP request from a server, not a browser.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Evert. At the moment, the problem is that we haven't back-end. The goal of this project is to use only front-end and API to get datas... So, if I understand well, there's no solutions with front-end only ?

Comment: @ViAct. No, if this were possible with a workaround, it means there would be a major security bug. There _are_ OAuth2 schemes that support frontends, but you need to use the `authorization_code` scheme, instead of `client_credentials`. I don't know if `enterprise.pole.emploi.fr` supports this, so this is something you might want to look into.

Comment: If you can successfully access the API outside of the browser then you can do the same when running your app on `localhost:4200` by setting up a proxy https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fixing-cors-errors-with-angular-cli-proxy-e5e0ef143f85